# Is the nilradical of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ equal to that of $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)/N$ where $N=\sqrt{(0)}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, nilpotence

**Question:** Determine the nilradical $N := \sqrt{(0)}$ in $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ and in $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z) /N$ .

My attempt: $\sqrt{(0)}=\{x+n\Bbb Z\in\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\ |\ \exists m\in\Bbb N\ x^m\in n\Bbb Z\}$ for the nilradical of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$

But the second case seems weird.

$$\sqrt{(0)}=\{(x+n\Bbb Z)+N\in (\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)/N \ |\ \exists k\in \Bbb N\ \text{s.t.}\  (x+n\Bbb Z)^k\in N\}\\=\{(x+n\Bbb Z)+N\in (\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)/N \ |\exists k\in \Bbb N\ \text{s.t.}\ \exists m\in\Bbb N\text{ s.t.} ((x+n\Bbb Z)^k)^m\in n\Bbb Z\}\\=\{(x+n\Bbb Z)+N\in (\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)/N \ |\exists l=k+m\in\Bbb N\text{ s.t.} (x+n\Bbb Z)^l\in n\Bbb Z\}\\=\sqrt{(0)}/N=\sqrt{(0)}$$

I don't know if this makes sense... I'm not sure if I correctly understand what $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)/N$ is.

For whatever ideal $I$ in $R\ ,\ $  $I=0+I\in R/I$ that's what quotienting is, hence my confusion

Comment: If $N$ is the "first" nilradical, than it cannot be "also the second one" (w.r.t. an other ring.) To be explicit. Let us consider an example, $n=108$. What is the situation / the problem explicitly in this case?

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator\rad{rad}$
Let $\varrho:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ be the canonical projection.
Since pre-image commutes with radical, we have
\begin{align}
&\varrho^{-1}N=\sqrt{n\Bbb Z}=\operatorname{rad}(n)\Bbb Z,&
&\operatorname{rad}(n):=\prod_{p\mid n}p
\end{align}
where the product runs over the prime divisors $p$ of $n$.
Since $\varrho$ is a surjective ring homomorphism we have
$$N=\operatorname{rad}(n)\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$$

Let $\psi:\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\to(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)/N$ be the canonical projection and $N'$ be the nilradical of $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)/N$.
Then
$$\psi^{-1}N'=\sqrt N=N$$
hence $N'=\{0\}$.